# storing a string(char*) in 2d array

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array

Say I have declared a 2d array like

```
char* array[30][30];
```

and what I am putting into it are strings, not all of length 30, like

```
char* string="test string";
```

I want to put each char of string into array starting at array[i][0]

I am trying to avoid using a loop to go over each character, is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: you've asked 7 questions and have not accepted one of them?

Comment: this syntax is so wrong it hurts, you're making a pointer to a char type value, then you instantiate as a physical 2d array...

Comment: Oh!! I was wondering what that 0% meant lol

Comment: @spatara now you are one hundred percent (lucky bastard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like:

```
strcpy(array[i], string):
```

I assume you also meant to declare your 2D array with:

```
char array[30][30];
```

Answer (score 0):

A 2 dimensional array of strings doesn't make such sense...

writing :

```
char * array[30];
```

is already a 2 dimensional array in a way.

Comment: To clarify, I do not want a 2d array of strings, I want to put each char in the string into my 2d array of chars

Comment: @spatara ok but to clarify `char * array[30]` will create an array of string but a string is also an array of char so you are like scratching your head for nothing cause to access an element of the structure I wrote you can write it like : `array[21][0]`. which means the first char of the 21th string on the abscissa